# object to fluid.form on other page

Tags: forms, typo3, fluid, extbase

Im trying to redirect from a list of entries to the edit page for these entries when an link.action is clicked.

I can't seem to get the values from the objects using the 'property' tag once I redirect to the editing page.
The action 'edit' is not getting executed on the page I redirect to. Instead it fires the standard action which is just listing all the entries.

```php
    public function toEditAction(Personenliste $person) {
        $this->redirect('edit', 'Listen', 'testprivateext', ['personenliste' => $person], 43);
    }

    public function editAction(Personenliste $person) {
        $this->view->assign('personenliste',$person);
        return $this->htmlResponse();
    }
```

The call is done via link.action. (I also tried directly redirecting the action with the 'pageUid'-tag)

```html
<f:link.action action="toEdit" arguments="{person:'{person}'}" extensionName="testprivateext" controller="Listen" pluginName="pi1">&#128393</f:link.action>
```

Comment: Okay. I ... fixed it? But to be honest I have no idea how I did this. I only copied the page in which I add more entries and changed everything so it resembles the edit page. Suddenly everything worked out perfectly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer to your question (because you already solved it), but a little info for more readable inline-fluid.
This:

```
arguments="{person:'{person}'}"
```

can be written:

```
arguments="{person: person}"
```

when you directly pass a variable, you can discard the quotes and curly braces.

but you will need it, when passing a VH:

```
arguments="{person:'{person -> f:format.raw()}'}"
```

Have a nice day :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it sometimes did not work when using it this way therefore I just tend to stick with the not so readable form. I'll try to use it that way more when providing SO with questions from now on.